# Get next week date in Spark Dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a DateType input in the function. I would like to exclude Saturday and Sunday and get the next week day, if the input date falls on the weekend, otherwise it should give the next day's date

Example:
Input: Monday 1/1/2017 output: 1/2/2017 (which is Tuesday)
Input: Saturday 3/4/2017 output: 3/5/2017 (which is Monday)

I have gone through https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html but I don't see a ready made function, so I think it will need to be created.

So far I have something that is:

```
val nextWeekDate = udf {(startDate: DateType) =>
val day= date_format(startDate,'E'
 if(day=='Sat' or day=='Sun'){
  nextWeekDate = next_day(startDate,'Mon')
}
 else{
   nextWeekDate =   date_add(startDate, 1)
 }
}
```

Need help to get it valid and working.

Comment: Your logic is good, but you need to use `when()` and `otherwise()` instead of `if` and `else`.  It's a common mistake when writing Spark code.  See my answer for a functioning version of your logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dates as strings:

```
import java.time.{DayOfWeek, LocalDate}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

// If that is your format date
object MyFormat {
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
}

object MainSample {
  import MyFormat._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import java.sql.Date
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DateType, IntegerType}

    import spark.implicits._  

    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StringType, StructField, StructType }
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    implicit val spark: SparkSession =
          SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("YourApp")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate()

    val someData = Seq(
      Row(1,"2013-01-30"),
      Row(2,"2012-01-01")
    )

    val schema = List(StructField("id", IntegerType), StructField("date",StringType))
    val sourceDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData), StructType(schema))

    sourceDF.show()

    val _udf = udf { (dt: String) =>
      // Parse your date, dt is a string
      val localDate = LocalDate.parse(dt, formatter)

      // Check the week day and add days in each case
      val newDate = if ((localDate.getDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)) {
        localDate.plusDays(2)
      } else if (localDate.getDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
        localDate.plusDays(1)
      } else {
        localDate.plusDays(1)
      }
      newDate.toString
    }

    sourceDF.withColumn("NewDate", _udf('date)).show()
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to spark-dataframe, can we use java libraries in spark dataframe and call it using scala like you have done? How do I call this udf , it doesn't seem to have a name?

Comment: Indee, LocalDate is not supported. You should work with java.sql.Date. Anyway, you can use the Date as a regular string and convert to LocalDate in your udf. The udf can be used operating your columns of your dataframe as you can see in the example I´ve just added.

Comment: I didn't get you. You said LocalDate is not supported, yet we are using LocalDate in the udf. So does it mean we can use java libraries in spark dataframes and call them using scala?

Comment: If you return in your udf a LocalDate type yo´ll get a message like: "Schema for type java.time.LocalDate is not supported". Instead, if you apply a .toString to your newDate it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much simpler answer that's defined in [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria):

```scala
def nextWeekday(col: Column): Column = {
  val d = dayofweek(col)
  val friday = lit(6)
  val saturday = lit(7)
  when(col.isNull, null)
    .when(d === friday || d === saturday, next_day(col,"Mon"))
    .otherwise(date_add(col, 1))
}
```

You always want to stick with the native Spark functions whenever possible.  This [post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/week-end-start-dayofweek-next-day/) explains the derivation of this function in greater detail.